# How to use an overridden migration class when running Knex migrations

Tags: node.js, typescript, knex.js

I am attempting to address an issue related to file extensions in Knex migrations. The most suitable solution I found involves re-implementing one of the Knex migration classes, as discussed in this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/4028#issuecomment-689683353). The suggested overridden FsMigrations class permits ignoring file extensions. An instance of FsMigrations is created in the Migrator class constructor within the getMergedConfig function call, as shown in the [Knex code](https://github.com/knex/knex/blob/b6d04f75b3c1956be8ffa26740dd1e27909dd25d/lib/migrations/migrate/Migrator.js#L44).

My question is: How can I "pass" the overridden version of FsMigrations to Knex, so that when an instance of the Migrator class is created, the custom FsMigrations implementation will be instantiated instead of the default one?

Answer (score 0):

Knex allows to pass [customer migration source](https://knexjs.org/guide/migrations.html#custom-migration-sources)